# Match domain name from url (www.google.com=google)

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

So I want to match just the domain from ether:

```
http://www.google.com/test/
http://google.com/test/
http://google.net/test/
```

**Output should be for all 3:** google

I got this code working for just .com

```
echo "http://www.google.com/test/" | sed -n "s/.*www\.\(.*\)\.com.*$/\1/p"
Output: 'google'
```

Then I thought it would be as simple as doing say (com|net) but that doesn't seem to be true:

```
echo "http://www.google.com/test/" | sed -n "s/.*www\.\(.*\)\.(com|net).*$/\1/p"
Output: '' (nothing)
```

I was going to use a similar method to get rid of the "www" but it seems im doing something wrong… (does it not work with regex outside the \(  \) …)

Comment: So long as you limit the problem domain (pun intended) to URL similar to the ones listed, regular expressions may adequately serve the purpose.  If you also need to deal with urls like "www.someuniverisity.ac.uk"  or "products.somecompany.co.jp" or even "www.cityofwherever.somestate.us", it may be advisable to use more expressive and general purpose languages (which possibly could leverage RE as part of the their parsing logic, but would also be able to implement a more complicated, and evolving, set of rules)

Comment: Technically, "google.com" and "www.google.com" *are* the domain names. You seem to be interested in the *second-level* domain name. :)

Comment: Yeah ok second-level domain, I knew I had the wrong term for it but I couldn't remember what it was called so I thought you would get what I meant with some examples :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will output "google" in all cases:

```
sed -n "s|http://\(.*\.\)*\(.*\)\..*|\2|p"
```

**Edit:**

This version will handle URLs like "'http://google.com.cn/test" and "http://www.google.co.uk/" as well as the ones in the original question:

```
sed -nr "s|http://(www\.)?([^.]*)\.(.*\.?)*|\2|p"
```

This version will handle cases that don't include "http://" (plus the others):

```
sed -nr "s|(http://)?(www\.)?([^.]*)\.(.*\.?)*|\3|p"
```

Comment: this fails on www.google.com.cn for example. Unless OP really doesn't have that kind of url to parse.

Comment: Ah yes this one works even better! Thanks Dennis, you seem to help me with allot of my questions :) (I should't need www.google.com.cn to work but you never know)

Answer (score 1):

if you have Python, you can use urlparse module

```
import urlparse
for http in open("file"):
    o = urlparse.urlparse(http)
    d = o.netloc.split(".")
    if "www" in o.netloc:
        print d[1]
    else:
        print d[0]
```

output

```
$ cat file
http://www.google.com/test/
http://google.com/test/
http://google.net/test/

$ ./python.py
google
google
google
```

or you can use awk

```
awk -F"/" '{
    gsub(/http:\/\/|\/.*$/,"")
    split($0,d,".")
    if(d[1]~/www/){
        print d[2]
    }else{
        print d[1]
    }
} ' file

$ cat file
http://www.google.com/test/
http://google.com/test/
http://google.net/test/
www.google.com.cn/test
google.com/test

$ ./shell.sh
google
google
google
google
google
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s|http://(www\.)?([^.]*)|$2|
```

It's Perl with alternate delimiters (because it makes it more legible), I'm sure you can port it to sed or whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the "-r" switch on your sed command? This enables the extended regular expression mode (egrep-compatible regexes).

Edit: try this, it seems to work. The "?:" characters in front of com|net are to prevent this set of characters to be captured by their surrounding parenthesis.

```
 echo "http://www.google.com/test/" | sed -nr "s/.*www\.(.*)\.(?:com|net).*$/\1/p"
```

Comment: Yep: user:~# echo "http\://www.google.com/test/" | sed -n -r "s/.*www\.\(.*\)\.(com|net).*$/\1/p"; returns nothing as does "-E" (take out the "\" from the url)

Comment: See my edited reply: since you are in extended regex mode, you don't need to escape your parenthesis to capture characters.

Comment: Thanks! *buys you a beer* (or what ever) :P I always get confused when and where not to use escapes.

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't notice that, though I would of when I started using it :P (but it helpful as I could edit his code to solve another of my problems :))

Comment: @Guillaume: The `:?` doesn't seem to work for me: `echo "aaabbbccc"|sed -nr 's/(a*)(:?b*)(c*)/\1 \2/p'` produces "aaa bbb"

Comment: `?:` gives me an error in `sed`. (by the way, you changed your description but not the command)

Answer (score 0):

```
#! /bin/bash

urls=(                        \
  http://www.google.com/test/ \
  http://google.com/test/     \
  http://google.net/test/     \
)

for url in ${urls[@]}; do
  echo $url | sed -re 's,^http://(.*\.)*(.+)\.[a-z]+/.+$,\2,'
done
```

Comment: this will not give correct results for url like www.google.com.cn